# wp7 get contact phone numbers but there is a error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

```
 private void abi3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//gonder
    {    
        foreach (var item in ContactResultsData.SelectedItems)
            {
                Contacts cons = new Contacts();
                cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>                 (Con_SearchCompleted);
                cons.SearchAsync(item.ToString(), FilterKind.DisplayName, null);

            }

  }



 void Con_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var contact in e.Results)
        {

            if (contact.PhoneNumbers.Count() > 0)
            {

                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ";" + contact.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault();

            }


        }
```

I am using this code for get phone numbers of my contacts. I have a listview and all contacts are in it. then I multi select and show the names and phones.

but for example, one of my contact name is "alex". the other is "alex de sousa".
when I select "alex" and "alex de sousa",
this program gets just alex's number twice.
no show the alex de soousa's number.

how can I solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it gets Alex's number twice and not Alex De Sousa's number twice and that they both have phone numbers set?

Comment: yes I am sure. for tring, I added just alex's and alex de sousa's numbers, and see that alex's number is twice and no alex de sousa's number.yes both of them have mobile phone number.

Comment: What's the value of `item.ToString()` on both loops?

Comment: sorry I am editing the message. the item.tostring is "alex" for one of them, and "alex de sousa" for the other.

Comment: and when I add one contact that is "alex de sousa", I see the number of alex. (alex is  upper than the alex de sousa in my listbox)

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening. From reading your code the only issue I can see is that Alex De Sousa's number would come up twice because when you search for `Alex`, two results should be returned (`Alex` and `Alex De Sousa`). Then you search for `Alex De Sousa` again so his number comes up again. At the moment, I can't see why only Alex's number is coming up if the search query is `Alex` and `Alex De Sousa` and they both have numbers returned (`contact.PhoneNumbers.Count() > 0`)

Comment: thanks for your replies. I solved some problems and now, when I search with "alex", it returns 2 phones. alex's and alex de sousa's numbers. how can eliminate the number one of them? ı want to see just alex's number when I search for alex.

Comment: How did you fix the problem? I've posted an answer to your new question.

Comment: I have a clear() function after these prosedure and my problem was in this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the updated question from the comments, you can check to see if the contact's `DisplayName` exactly matches the search query.

Pass in the query as the object's state like this

```
cons.SearchAsync(item.ToString(), FilterKind.DisplayName, item.ToString());
```

Then read the state in the `SearchCompleted` event and see if it's an exact match like this

```
if (contact.PhoneNumbers.Count() > 0 && String.Equals(contact.DisplayName, e.State.ToString()))
```

Comment: No problem. Please accept if this answered your question so that the thread can be marked as solved.

Comment: how can I do it.any button here?

Comment: underneath the down arrow there should be a check mark. Just click it